# Fancybox3: How to create separate galleries on a single page while keeping the data-trigger attribute?

Tags: datatrigger, fancybox-3

I'm not sure how to create separate galleries while using the data-trigger attribute. On the same page I want to be able to hit different buttons to different video and image galleries.

Here's the code...

```
<div id="porfolio-animation">
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="portfolio-headers">animation</h1>
    <img class="displayed">

    <a data-trigger="preview01" href="javascript:;"> 
    <img src="images/animation-btn.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Animation portfolio">
    </a>

    <a href="https://vimeo.com/148636779" data-fancybox="preview01">
    </a>

    <a href="https://vimeo.com/227570106" data-fancybox="preview01">
    </a>

    <a href="https://vimeo.com/277458775" data-fancybox="preview01">
    </a>

<div class="portfolio-illo">

    <a data-trigger="preview02" href="javascript:;"> 
    <img src="images/illo-btn.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Illustration portfolio">
    </a>

    <a href="images/fastfood_coffee_illo_web.jpg" data-fancybox="preview02">
    </a>

    <h1 class="portfolio-headers">illustration</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to create separate galleries": what did you try?

Comment: I tried to use rel="gallery01" but that didn't work. I'm new to coding so I'm not sure where else to experiment.

Comment: 1) The documentation contains info about creating galleries - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage 2) And there is not a word about using `rel` attribute, so, why did you expect it to work?